# error creating dynamic controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am supposed to create a `Label` and `TextBox` when `CheckBoxList` event `SelectedIndexChanged` fires.

I tried with the following code, but it is giving me this error:

> Multiple controls with the same ID 'mylab1' were found

```
protected void chkCar_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Panel2.Controls.Clear();
    string dat = DateTime.Parse(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    lblName.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < chkCar.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        if (chkCar.Items[i].Selected == true)
        {
            Panel tt = new Panel();
            Panel2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            Label mylab = new Label();
            mylab.ID = "mylab" + NextID1;
            mylab.Text = "No of Persons in " + chkCar.Items[i].Value;
            Panel2.Controls.Add(mylab);
            ControlsList1.Add(mylab.ID);

            TextBox mytext = new TextBox();
            mytext.ID = "mytext" + NextID2;
            mytext.Text = "";
            Panel2.Controls.Add(mytext);
            ControlsList2.Add(mytext.ID);
        }
    }
}

protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);
    foreach (string lbID in ControlsList1)
    {
        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.ID = lbID;
        Panel2.Controls.Add(lb);
        Panel2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
    }
    foreach (string txtID in ControlsList2)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = txtID;
        Panel2.Controls.Add(tb);
        Panel2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
    }
}

private List<string> ControlsList1 //labels
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["controls"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["controls"] = new List<string>();
        }
        return (List<string>)ViewState["controls"];
    }                     
}

private List<string> ControlsList2 //textboxes
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["controls"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["controls"] = new List<string>();
        }
        return (List<string>)ViewState["controls"];
    }
}

private int NextID1//label
{
    get
    {
        return ControlsList1.Count + 1;
    }
}

private int NextID2//textbox
{
    get
    {
        return ControlsList2.Count + 1;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me knowing where I'm going wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that to make that work you need to add your newly added controls ids to `ControlsList1` and `ControlsList2`, otherwise `NextID1` and `NextID2` will always return the same number during the `for` loop.

```
if (chkCar.Items[i].Selected == true)
{
    Panel tt = new Panel();
    Panel2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    Label mylab = new Label();
    mylab.ID = "mylab" + NextID1;
    mylab.Text = "No of Persons in " + chkCar.Items[i].Value;
    Panel2.Controls.Add(mylab);
    ControlsList1.Add(mylab.ID) // <--- here

    TextBox mytext = new TextBox();
    mytext.ID = "mytext" + NextID2;
    mytext.Text = "";
    Panel2.Controls.Add(mytext);
    ControlsList2.Add(mytext.ID) // <--- and here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be just try not to load `ViewState` and clear your controls every time you fire your checkbox event. By the way why are you loading `ViewState`? And if `ViewState` already loads your controls and then your checkbox again tries to load controls in your panel.

Its a blind shot hope it works.

Comment: View State because after the postback, dynamically created labels and textboxes disappear. So i tried adding the loadviewstate.

Comment: Well i faced similar problem where i created dynamic controls , viewstate retains control values during postback but it does not recreate dynamically added controls ,So it may be possible when ur viewstate try to add new controls same controls with similar id are already present in viewstate.   Please check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i if it helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your method `NextID1` that is generating increamented ids, it is not giving you unique numbers. You can use loop variable to make ids unique. I could not seen any code for adding control to `ControlsList1` so that the Method NextID1 gives next number every time control in added to `ControlsList1`

```
private int NextID1//label
{
    get
    {
        return ControlsList1.Count + 1;
    }
}
```

You are also not putting (assigning) `ControlsList1` to `ViewState`

Comment: I tried with adding loop variable and assigning ID but showin the same error

Comment: You should debug the code to see, you must be generating same id, try to use GUID as id just for testing.